# python mysql : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, mysql, spyder

I get the following error message

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' in  41 in
>
> create_database (connection, create_database_query)
>
> 33 in create_database
> cursor = connection.cursor()

my code is

```
def create_database(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        print ("Database created successfully")
    except Error as err:
        print (f"Error: '{err}'")
  
create_database_query = "Create Database Donations"
create_database (connection, create_database_query)
        
def execute_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        print ("Query sucessful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your **connection var** is None. Maybe you are passing the wrong variable or didn't instance the connection well

Comment: im using https://github.com/thecraigd/Python_SQL/blob/master/mysql.ipynb

but editing it along the way with what i need my project to be